# How to fill some packets in a queue in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code which produces two queues. I would like to fill the first packet of the first queue with black (or any other color) and keep the second queue unfilled. Can I do this without changing a lot my code?

The code [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230979/how-to-draw-a-parallel-network-of-queues):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\tikzset{
    queuei/.pic={
        \draw[line width=1pt]
        (0,0) -- ++(2cm,0) -- ++(0,-1cm) -- ++(-2cm,0);
        \foreach \Val in {1,...,3}
        \draw ([xshift=-\Val*10pt]2cm,0) -- ++(0,-1cm);
        \node[above] at (1cm,0) {Queue $#1$};   
    },
}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
% the shapes
\path 
(0,3cm) pic {queuei=1}
(0,1cm) pic {queuei=2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

N.B. The desired output is as follows:
[image]

Comment: If it is only the last rectangle you are interested, then you can add `[pic actions]` key to that rectangle. Then when you write `pic[fill=red]` it will be passed to `pic actions`. But you need to modify creating the little box drawing accordingly maybe taking it out of for each loop and drawing explicitly. See the manual for `pic actions`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd propose you a little modification to your `pic` using a `rectangle split` shape from the `shapes.multipart` library, which allows filling for the parts:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,shapes.multipart}

\newcounter{cntr}
\tikzset{
    queuei/.pic={
  \stepcounter{cntr}
        \node[outer sep=0pt,draw,rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal,minimum height=1cm,rectangle split parts=3] (queue-\thecntr) [pic actions] {};
        \draw 
          (queue-\thecntr.north west) -- ++(-1cm,0)
          (queue-\thecntr.south west) -- ++(-1cm,0);
        \node[above] at ([xshift=-0.5cm]queue-\thecntr.north) {Queue $#1$};   
    },
}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
% the shapes
\path 
(0,3cm) pic[rectangle split part fill={white,white,gray!80}] {queuei=1}
(0,1cm) pic {queuei=2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]